# Image handing: file path + uri + exif data (rotation) issues

Tags: android, image-processing, android-intent, android-camera-intent, android-crop

I've been struggling for days to create an activity that picks a image from the camera and crops it into a square shape efficiently (not loading the image into memory).

Taking the picture is no big deal:

```
Intent mediaPickingIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
mediaPickingIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

startActivityForResult(mediaPickingIntent, REQUEST_CODE_GENERIC);
```

Then, I'm trying to use the OOTB cropping feature for each device like:

```
String cropDestinationPath = getTemporaryImagePath();
Uri destination = Uri.fromFile(new File(cropDestinationPath));

Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
cropIntent.setDataAndType(source, "image/*");
cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", SQUARE_IMAGE_SIZE);
cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", SQUARE_IMAGE_SIZE);
cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", false);
cropIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, destination);

startActivityForResult(cropIntent, REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE_CROP);
```

Now, using the output path of the IMAGE_CAPTURE, I'm able to retrieve the exif data that says the image is rotated (i.e: 270 degrees) but the intent seems to be not caring the exif data.

I'm transforming the resulting path to an uri like:

```
    private Uri convertPathToContentUri(String imagePath) throws Exception {
            String imageName = null;
            String imageDescription = null;
            String uriString = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), imagePath, imageName, imageDescription);
            return Uri.parse(uriString);
    }
```

BTW: I'm testing this on a Samsung device, same code on Nexus works fine.

Comment: "Taking the picture is no big deal" -- there is no `outputFormat` extra for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. "I'm trying to use the OOTB cropping feature" -- [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are many [image cropping libraries for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one.

Comment: Thanks. Any specific you can recommend to be used with the camera?

Comment: Well, you will probably get JPEG by default, as few camera apps support anything else. However, do note that camera apps are buggy, so be sure to have code that sees if the image actually exists at your `EXTRA_OUTPUT` location. Also note that [support for `file:` `Uri` values is going away](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html), if that is what you are using for `EXTRA_OUTPUT`.

Comment: Ha! yes, that's what I'm doing. how do I suppose to provide an output for the camera then? Can't believe this is so complicated...

Comment: Presumably, we're supposed to use some form of `ContentProvider`, such as `FileProvider`. I haven't tried this for supplying `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, but it's on my to-do list.